# fetch gives response Unexpected token < in JSON

Tags: reactjs

How can I fetch local json.  the error says `Unexpected token < ..`. I have no network error.

Itemslist.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Itemslist extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('items.json').then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      // return res.json()
    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
}
```

below is the response I get in dev tools

```
Response {type: "basic", url: 
"http://localhost:5000/items.json", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:5000/items.json"
__proto__: Response
```

although the response is 200, I get the below error:

```
 bundle.js:30 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Project Structure:

```
|---static
|   |---reactApp
|       |--components
|       |  |--items.json
|       |  |--Itemslist.js
|       |
|       |--App.js
```

Comment: Also, it looks like your items.json is not located inside the public folder used to serve the file from the server. If you want to use the items.json, maybe `import` it instead ?

Comment: do you mean local json should only be imported not fetched?

Comment: Oh, sorry, for some reason I thought you were getting a local file, my bad. Whether or not you want to import it depends on whether or not you you're just testing something--if it's just a JSON file representing static JS, just use JS, and import it.

Answer (score 11):

`Unexpected token < ..` means JSON parsing failed because you somehow get HTML while expecting JSON. Please check the response of `http://localhost:5000/items.json` is really valid JSON.

An easy way to check would be to change the code to `res.text()` and log the result to the console.

Comment: you were right. I'm fetching html back but not json. I tried to move the items.json file to dist folder. (My understanding is that dist acts as public folder since all minified goes into it.) And tried making a fetch but i'm still getting `token < ..` error. I tried to set` Accept: 'application/json'` and got same error. Any idea what is wrong?