# Error occurred while trying to proxy request (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

This might be marked as a duplicate but I looked at all the Stack Overflow posts on this topic. I also listed some of them below. Many of the posts on this topic also didn't have a correct answer "ticked".

I have a React app that I wish to connect to a Node server using Express. It is the first time I do this so I followed this post https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-app-with-node-js-server-proxy. I followed all the instructions, as far as I can see, I have checked several times. So I went and did research to see if I can figure out what the problem is.

When I run `npm run dev` to start up both the sever and the React app, the React app shows correctly in my browser. However when I type my name in the textbox I get the following error in my terminal:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/greeting?name=Johnnie from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/ (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

In my console on the front-end I get:

```
VM92:1 GET http://localhost:3000/api/greeting?name=Johnnie 504 (Gateway Timeout)
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0
Fetch failed loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/api/greeting?name=Johnnie.
```

I did hours of research and followed some instructions on the following StackOverflow posts:

[React Js: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269808/react-js-uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-posit)

[Fetching JSON returns error Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 and status code 304: Not Modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368716/fetching-json-returns-error-uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token/55628120)

[fetch gives response Unexpected token < in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992070/fetch-gives-response-unexpected-token-in-json)

["React Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/ from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000 (ECONNREFUSED)'? Error.. No solution online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62227839/react-proxy-error-could-not-proxy-request-api-from-localhost3000-to-http)

……and more

I added a setupProxy.js file too.

Here is my package .json snippet:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "node-env-run server --exec nodemon | pino-colada",
    "dev": "run-p server start"
  },
  "proxy": "https://localhost:3001/",
```

My .env

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3001
```

setupProxy.js

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware("/api/*", { target: "http://localhost:3001/" }));
};
```

server/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const pino = require('express-pino-logger')();
const PORT = 3001;

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(pino);

app.get('/api/greeting', (req, res) => {
  const name = req.query.name || 'World';
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ greeting: `Hello ${name}!` }));
});

app.listen(3001, () =>
  console.log('Express server is running on localhost:3001')
);
```

The handleSubmit function in App.js

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch(`/api/greeting?name=${encodeURIComponent(this.state.name)}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(state => this.setState(state));
  }
```

I know the issue has to do with the server and app not running concurrently but I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: Did you solve it? I am struggling with same

Comment: Yes I did. If I remember correctly it had to do with my file structure. What is your file structure? Where is your server code? I will look later at my code to see, I'm not on my computer and can't remember exactly

Answer (score -2):

You can find solution from [here](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/171)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).